# I went in, booted as I was. (Is this same as?: I went in though I was booted.)

Tags: meaning-in-context, conjunctions

I went in, booted as I was. (Is this same as?: I went in though I was booted.)

I think booted as I was is a concessive clause.

Comment: I think it just means he didn't change his shoes first.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, here *as* is a conjunction that means *although/though* and is used [to express concession](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/as#Conjunction).

Answer (score 1):

I would need more context to know definitely. I can understand the way you've interpreted it, but I'd read

> booted as I was

as a simple description, i.e. the person has not changed his shoes before entering.